# How to define similar bash function at once

Tags: bash

I have these functions in `~/.bashrc`:

```
function guard() {
    if [ -e 'Gemfile' ]; then
    bundle exec guard "$@"
    else
    command guard "$@"
    fi
}
function rspec() {
    if [ -e 'Gemfile' ]; then
    bundle exec rspec "$@"
    else
    command rspec "$@"
    fi
}
function rake() {
    if [ -e 'Gemfile' ]; then
        bundle exec rake "$@"
    else
        command rake "$@"
    fi
}
```

As you see these functions are very similar. I want to define these 3 functions at once. Is there a way to make it?

*environment*

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

for func in guard rspec rake; do
        eval "
        ${func}() {
                local foo=(command ${func})
                [ -e 'Gemfile' ] && foo=(bundle exec ${func})
                \"\${foo[@]}\" \"\$@\"
        }
        "
done

type guard rspec rake
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
guard is a function
guard ()
{
    local foo=(command guard);
    [ -e 'Gemfile' ] && foo=(bundle exec guard);
    "${foo[@]}" "$@"
}
rspec is a function
rspec ()
{
    local foo=(command rspec);
    [ -e 'Gemfile' ] && foo=(bundle exec rspec);
    "${foo[@]}" "$@"
}
rake is a function
rake ()
{
    local foo=(command rake);
    [ -e 'Gemfile' ] && foo=(bundle exec rake);
    "${foo[@]}" "$@"
}
```

The usual cautions about `eval` apply.

Comment: Does it not get eaten by the *`for loop?`* I mean, variables declared in a *`for loop`* generally disappear - I would expect the same of functions for the same reasons.

Comment: What makes you think that? `bash -c 'for i in 1; do :; done; echo $i'` => `1`. The `type` clearly shows that the functions exist outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: @mikeserv Even with `bash`'s dynamic scoping all you can get is a `local` variable local to the scope of a *whole function*, variables do definitely not "disappear" after a loop. In fact, since there is no function involved here it's not even possible to define a `local` variable in this case.

Comment: Right - local to the for loop - they're locally scoped. They do disappear as soon as their parent loop shell does. Does this not happen here?

Comment: No, as I just explained there is no such concept as "local to the for loop" in shell scripting and my post and the example in my comment above clearly show that.

Comment: Now I'm a little confused - I always try to use *`sh`* for testing so I rarely even touch *`bash.`* But I don't mean anything derogatory of course - just curious. Your answer is a lot like mine in result just different in method. I'm just curious how it works. Like look at this: bash -c 'for v in a b c d e f ; do { z="${z}${v}" ; } ; done ; echo "$v"'                                          ⏎
abcdef

Comment: No offense taken :-) Shall we take this to the chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13722/discussion-between-mikeserv-and-adrian-fruhwirth)

Answer (score 7):

```
_gem_dec() { shift $# ; . /dev/fd/3
} 3<<-FUNC
    _${1}() { [ ! -e 'Gemfile' ] && { 
        command $1 "\$@" ; return \$?
        } || bundle exec $1 "\$@"
    }
FUNC
for func in guard rspec rake ; do _gem_dec $func ; done
echo "_guard ; _rspec ; _rake are all functions now."
```

The above will *`. source /dev/fd/3`* which is fed into the *`_gem_dec()`* function every time it is called as a pre-evaluated *`here-document. _gem_dec's`* only job is to receive one parameter and pre-evaluate it as both the *`bundle exec`* target and as the name of the function in which it is targeted.

***`NOTE: . sourcing shell expansions results in twice-evaluated variables - just like eval. It can be risky.`***

In the above case though, I don't think there can be any risk.

If the above code-block is copied into a *`.bashrc`* file, not only will the shell functions *`_guard(), _rspec()` and `_rake()`* be declared at login, but the *`_gem_dec()`* function will also be available for execution at any time at your shell prompt *(or otherwise)* and so ***new templated functions can be declared whenever you like with just:***

```
_gem_dec $new_templated_function_name
```

And thanks to @Andrew for showing me these wouldn't get eaten by a *`for loop.`*

#### BUT HOW?

I use the *`3`* file descriptor above to keep *`stdin, stdout, and stderr, or <&0 >&1 >&2`* open out of habit - though, as is also the case for a few of the other default precautions I implement here - because the resulting function is so simple, it's really not necessary. It is good practice, though. Calling *`shift $#`* is another of those unnecessary precautions.

Still, when a file is specified as *`<input` or `>output`* with *`[optional num]<file` or `[optional num]>file` redirection* the kernel reads it into a file descriptor, which can be accessed via the *`character device`* special files in *`/dev/fd/[0-9]*`.* If the *`[optional num]`* specifier is omitted, then *`0<file`* is assumed for input and *`1>file`* for output. Consider this:

```
l='line %d\n' ; printf "$l" 1 2 3 4 5 6 >/dev/fd/1
> line 1
> line 2
> line 3
> line 4
> line 5
> line 6

( printf "$l" 4 5 6 >/dev/fd/3 ; printf "$l" 1 2 3 ) >/tmp/sample 3>/tmp/sample2

( cat /tmp/sample2 ) </tmp/sample
> line 4
> line 5
> line 6

( cat /dev/fd/0 ) </tmp/sample
> line 1
> line 2
> line 3

( cat /dev/fd/3 ) </tmp/sample 3</tmp/sample2
> line 4
> line 5
> line 6
```

And because a *`here-document`* is only a means of describing a file inline within a code-block, when we do:

```
<<'HEREDOC'
[$CODE]
HEREDOC
```

We might as well do:

```
echo '[$CODE]' >/dev/fd/0
```

With one *very important* distinction. If you do not *`"'\quote'"`* the *`<<"'\LIMITER"'`* of a *`here-document`* then the shell will evaluate it for shell *`$expansion`* like:

```
echo "[$CODE]" >/dev/fd/0
```

So, for *`_gem_dec()`,* the *`3<<-FUNC here-document`* is evaluated as a file on input, the same as it would be if it were *`3<~/some.file` **except*** that because we leave the *`FUNC` limiter* free of quotes, it is first evaluated for *`$expansion.`* The important thing about this is that it is input, meaning it only exists for *`_gem_dec(),`* but that it is also evaluated before the *`_gem_dec()`* function runs because our shell has to read and evaluate its *`$expansions` before* handing it off as input.

Lets do *`guard,`* for example:

```
_gem_dec guard
```

So first the shell has to handle the input, which means reading:

```
3<<-FUNC
    _${1}() { [ ! -e 'Gemfile' ] && { 
        command $1 "\$@" ; return \$?
        } || bundle exec $1 "\$@"
    }
FUNC
```

Into file descriptor 3 and evaluating it for shell expansion. If at this time you ran:

```
cat /dev/fd/3
```

Or:

```
cat <&3
```

Since they're both equivalent commands you'd see*:

```
_guard() { [ ! -e 'Gemfile' ] && { 
    command guard "$@" ; return $?
    } || bundle exec guard "$@"
}
```

...before ever any code in the function executes at all. This is the function's *`<input`,* after all. For more examples see my answer to a different question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120863/52934).

*( * Technically this isn't completely true. Because I use a leading `-dash` before the `here-doc limiter`, the above would all be left-justified. But I used the `-dash` so I could `<tab-insert>` for readability in the first place so I'm not going to strip the `<tab-inserts>` before offering it to you to read...)*

The nicest part about this is the quoting - notice that the *`'"`* quotes remain and only the *`\`* quotes were stripped. It is probably for this reason more than any other that if you have to twice-evaluate a shell *`$expansion`* I will recommend the *`here-document`* because the quotes are *much* easier than *`eval`.*

Anyway, now the above code is exactly like a file fed in like *`3<~/heredoc.file`* just waiting for the *`_gem_dec()`* function to get going and accept its input on *`/dev/fd/3`.*

So when we do start *`_gem_dec()`* the first thing I do is toss *all* positional parameters, because our next step is a twice-evaluated shell expansion and I don't want any of the contained *`$expansions`* to be interpreted as any of my current *`$1 $2 $3...`* parameters. So I:

```
shift $#
```

*`shift`* discards as many *`positional parameters`* as you specify and starts from *`$1`* with what remains. So if I called *`_gem_dec one two three`* at the prompt *`_gem_dec's $1 $2 $3`* positional parameters would be *`one two three`* and the total current positional count, or *`$#`* would be 3. If I then called *`shift 2,`* the values of *`one` and `two`* would be *`shift`ed* away, the value of *`$1`* would change to *`three`* and *`$#`* would expand to *1.* So *`shift $#`* just throws them all away. Doing this is strictly precautionary and is just a habit I've developed after doing this kind of thing for awhile.
Here it is in a *`(subshell)`* spread out a little for clarity's sake:

```
( set -- one two three ; echo "$1 $2 $3" ; echo $# )
> one two three
> 3

( set -- one two three ; shift 2 ; echo "$1 $2 $3" ; echo $# )
> three
> 1

( set -- one two three ; shift $# ; echo "$1 $2 $3" ; echo $# )
>
> 0
```

Anyway, the next step is where the magic happens. If you *`. ~/some.sh`* at the shell prompt then all the functions and environment variables declared in *`~/some.sh`* would then be callable at your shell prompt. The same is true here, except we *`. source`*  the *`character device`* special file for our file descriptor, or *`. /dev/fd/3`* - which is where our *`here-document`* in-line file has been pathed - and we've declared our function. And that's how it works.

```
_guard
```

Now does whatever your *`_guard`* function is supposed to do.

Addendum:

A great way to say save your positionals:

```
f() { . /dev/fd/3
} 3<<-ARGS
    args='${args:-"$@"}'
ARGS
```

#### EDIT:

When I first answered this question I focused more on the problem of declaring a shell *`function()`* capable of declaring other functions that would persist in the current shell *`$ENV`ironment* than I did on what the asker would do with said persistent functions. Since then I've realized that my originally proffered solution in which *`3<<-FUNC`* took the form:

```
3<<-FUNC
    _${1}() { 
        if [ -e 'Gemfile' ]; then
            bundle exec $1 "\$@"
        else 
            command _${1} "\$@"
    }
FUNC
```

Would likely not have worked as expected for the asker because I specifically altered the declarative function's name from *`$1`* to *`_${1}`* which, if called like *`_gem_dec guard`* for example, would result in *`_gem_dec`* declaring a function named *`_guard`* as opposed to just *`guard`.*

***Note:*** Such behavior is a matter of habit for me - I typically operate on the presumption that shell functions should occupy *only* their own *`_namespace`* in order avoid their intrusion on the *`namespace`* of shell *`commands`* proper.

This is not a universal habit, though, as is evinced in the asker's use of *`command`* to call upon *`$1`.*

Further examination leads me to believe the following:

> The asker wants shell functions named *`guard, rspec, or rake`* that, when called, will compile anew a *`ruby`* function of the same name *`if`* the file *`Gemfile`* exists in *`$PATH` **OR*** 
>   *`if Gemfile`* does not exist, the shell function should execute the *`ruby`* function of the same name.

This would not have worked previously because I also altered the *`$1`* called upon by *`command`* to read:

```
command _${1}
```

Which would not have resulted in execution of the *`ruby`* function that the shell function compiled as:

```
bundle exec $1
```

I hope you can see *(as eventually I did)* that it seems the asker is only using *`command`* at all to indirectly specify *`namespace`* because *`command`* will prefer to call an executable file in *`$PATH`* over a shell function of the same name.

If my analysis is correct *(as I hope the asker will confirm)* then this:

```
_${1}() { [ ! -e 'Gemfile' ] && { 
    command $1 "\$@" ; return \$?
    } || bundle exec $1 "\$@"
}
```

Should better satisfy those conditions with the exception that calling *`guard`* at the prompt will *only* attempt to execute an executable file in *`$PATH`* named *`guard`* whereas calling *`_guard`* at the prompt will check for *`Gemfile's`* existence and compile accordingly *or* execute the *`guard`* executable in *`$PATH`.* In this way *`namespace`* is protected and, at least as I perceive it, the asker's intent is still fulfilled.

In fact, presuming our shell function *`_${1}()`* and the executable *`${PATH}/${1}`* are the *only* two ways our shell could interpret a call to either *`$1`* or *`_${1}`* then the use of *`command`* in the function at all is now made entirely redundant. Still, I've let it remain as I don't like to make the same mistake twice... in a row anyway.

If this is unacceptable to the asker and he/she would prefer to do away with the *`_`* entirely then, in its current form, editing the *`_underscore`* out should be all the asker need do to meet his/her requirements as I understand them.

Aside from that change I have also edited the function to use *`&&` and/or `||`* shell *short-circuit* conditionals rather than the original *`if/then`* syntax. In this way the *`command`* statement is only evaluated *at all* if *`Gemfile`* is not in *`$PATH`.* This modification does require the addition of *`return $?`* however to ensure the *`bundle`* statement is not run in the event *`Gemfile`* doesn't exist but the *`ruby $1`* function returns anything other than *0.*

Last, I should note that this solution implements only portable shell constructs. In other words, this should produce identical results in any shell claiming POSIX compatibility. While it would, of course, be nonsense for me to claim every POSIX-compatible system must handle the *`ruby bundle`* directive, at least the shell imperatives calling upon it should behave the same regardless of whether the calling shell is *`sh` or `dash`.* Also the above will work as expected *(presuming at least halfway-sane `shopts` anyway)* in both *`bash` and `zsh`.*

Comment: I put your code into `~/.bashrc` and call `. ~/.bashrc`, then these three function are executed. Maybe the behavior differs by environment, so I added my environment to the question. Besides I couldn't understand why last line `_guard ; _rspec ; _rake` is needed. I searched about `shift` and file descriptor, it looks like these are beyond my current understanding.

Comment: I just put that there to show they were callable. Sorry - I put in an echo now. So you can call them as functions, as you've demonstrated.

Comment: @Tetsu - does it make better sense now?

Comment: I read through your answer 3 times, but honestly saying I need more knowledge to understand the explanation. Even though I'm very grateful you, I'll read it again when I get more experience.

Comment: @Tetsu Perhaps it is clearer now...? I think I realized, and have now corrected, a mistake I made previously. Please let me know, if you would.

Answer (score 2):

```
function threeinone () {
    local var="$1"
    if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    if ! [ "$1" = "guard" -o "$1" = "rspec" -o "$1" = "rake" ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    shift
    if [ -e 'Gemfile' ]; then
        bundle exec "$var" "$@"
    else
        command "$var" "$@"
    fi
}

threeinone guard
threeinone rspec
threeinone rake
```