# A bash function that takes argument like other languages?

Tags: bash, bash-script

I have a bash function to set the `$PATH` like this --

```
assign-path()
{
    str=$1
    # if the $PATH is empty, assign it directly.
    if [ -z $PATH ]; then
        PATH=$str;
    # if the $PATH does not contain the substring, append it with ':'.
    elif [[ $PATH != *$str* ]]; then
        PATH=$PATH:$str;
    fi
}
```

But the problem is, I have to write different function for different variables (for example, another function for `$CLASSPATH` like `assign-classpath()` etc.). I could not find a way to pass argument to the bash function so that I can access it by reference.

It would be better if I had something like --

```
assign( bigstr, substr )
{
    if [ -z bigstr ]; then
        bigstr=substr;
    elif [[ bigstr != *str* ]]; then
        bigstr=bigstr:substr;
    fi
}
```

Any idea, how to achieve something like above in bash?

Comment: What "other languages"?

Comment: well, I tried to mean if bash allows "pass by reference" like in c/java etc.

Comment: `assign-path /abc` will not append `/abc` to PATH if $PATH already contains `/abc/def`, `/abcd`, `/def/abc` etc. Especially  you can't add `/bin` if PATH already contains `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @miracle173 - this is true, what you need to do is split *`$PATH`* and negate test against your arguments like: *`add=/bin dir=/usr/bin ; [ -z "${dir%"$add"}" ] || dir="${dir}:${add}"`.* In my answer I do it this way with as many arguments as you like only using *`IFS=:`.*

Comment: Related to the specific (instance) issue of adding values to colon-separated lists: [How can I cleanly add to ``$PATH``?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124444/23408) and [Add directory to ``$PATH`` if it’s not already there](https://superuser.com/q/39751/150988) (on [SU]).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `bash` you can use `${!varname}` to expand the variable referenced by the contents of another. Eg:

```
$ var=hello
$ foo () { echo "${!1}"; }
$ foo var
hello
```

From the man page:

```
${!prefix*}
${!prefix@}
       Names matching prefix.  Expands to the names of variables whose names
       begin with prefix, separated by the first character of the IFS special
       variable.  When @ is used  and the expansion appears within double quotes,
       each variable name expands to a separate word.
```

Also, to set a variable referenced by the contents (without the dangers of `eval`), you can use `declare`. Eg:

```
$ var=target
$ declare "$var=hello"
$ echo "$target"
hello
```

Thus, you could write your function like this (take care because if you use `declare` in a function, you must give `-g` or the variable will be local):

```
shopt -s extglob

assign()
{
  target=$1
  bigstr=${!1}
  substr=$2

  if [ -z "$bigstr" ]; then
    declare -g -- "$target=$substr"
  elif [[ $bigstr != @(|*:)$substr@(|:*) ]]; then
    declare -g -- "$target=$bigstr:$substr"
  fi
}
```

And use it like:

```
assign PATH /path/to/binaries
```

Note that I have also corrected an bug where if `substr` is already a substring of one of the colon separated members of `bigstr`, but not its own member, then it wouldn't be added. For example, this would allow adding `/bin` to a `PATH` variable already containing `/usr/bin`. It uses the `extglob` sets to match either the beginning/end of the string or a colon then anything else. Without `extglob`, the alternative would be:

```
[[ $bigstr != $substr && $bigstr != *:$substr &&
   $bigstr != $substr:* && $bigstr != *:$substr:* ]]
```

Comment: `-g` in `declare` is not available in older version of bash, is there any way so that I can make this backward compatible?

Comment: @ramgorur, you could use `export` to put it in your environment (at the risk of overwriting something important) or `eval` (various issues including security if you are not careful). If using `eval` you *should* be ok if you do it like `eval "$target=\$substr"`. If you forget the `\ ` though, it will potentially execute a command if there is a space in the contents of `substr`.

Answer (score 10):

New in bash 4.3, is the `-n` option to `declare` & `local`:

```bash
func() {
    local -n ref="$1"
    ref="hello, world"
}

var='goodbye world'
func var
echo "$var"
```

That prints out `hello, world`.

Comment: The only problem with namerefs in Bash is that you can't have a nameref (in a function for example) referencing a variable (outside the function) of the same name as the nameref itself. This may be fixed for release 4.5 though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` to set a parameter. A description of this command can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23117/17485). The following usage of `eval` is wrong:

```
wrong(){
  eval $1=$2
}
```

With respect to the additional evaluation `eval`does you should use

```
assign(){
  eval $1='$2'
}
```

Check the results of using these functions:

```
$ X1='$X2'
$ X2='$X3'
$ X3='xxx'
$ 
$ echo :$X1:
:$X2:
$ echo :$X2:
:$X3:
$ echo :$X3:
:xxx:
$ 
$ wrong Y $X1
$ echo :$Y:
:$X3:
$ 
$ assign Y $X1
$ echo :$Y:
:$X2:
$ 
$ assign Y "hallo world"
$echo :$Y:
:hallo world:
$ # the following may be unexpected
$ assign Z $Y
$ echo ":$Z:"
:hallo:
$ # so you have to quote the second argument if its a variable
$ assign Z "$Y"
$ echo ":$Z:"
:hallo world:
```

But you can achieve your goal without the usage of `eval`. I prefer this way that is more simple.

The following function makes the substitution in the right way (I hope)

```
augment(){
  local CURRENT=$1
  local AUGMENT=$2
  local NEW
  if [[ -z $CURRENT ]]; then
    NEW=$AUGMENT
  elif [[ ! ( ( $CURRENT = $AUGMENT ) || ( $CURRENT = $AUGMENT:* ) || \
    ( $CURRENT = *:$AUGMENT ) || ( $CURRENT = *:$AUGMENT:* ) ) ]]; then
    NEW=$CURRENT:$AUGMENT
  else
    NEW=$CURRENT
    fi
  echo "$NEW"
}
```

Check the following output

```
augment /usr/bin /bin
/usr/bin:/bin

augment /usr/bin:/bin /bin
/usr/bin:/bin

augment /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin /bin
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin

augment /bin:/usr/bin /bin
/bin:/usr/bin

augment /bin /bin
/bin


augment /usr/bin: /bin
/usr/bin::/bin

augment /usr/bin:/bin: /bin
/usr/bin:/bin:

augment /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin: /bin
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:

augment /bin:/usr/bin: /bin
/bin:/usr/bin:

augment /bin: /bin
/bin:


augment : /bin
::/bin


augment "/usr lib" "/usr bin"
/usr lib:/usr bin

augment "/usr lib:/usr bin" "/usr bin"
/usr lib:/usr bin
```

Now you can use the `augment` function in the following way to set a variable:

```
PATH=`augment PATH /bin`
CLASSPATH=`augment CLASSPATH /bin`
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`augment LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib`
```

Comment: Even your eval statement is wrong. This, for example: `v='echo "OHNO!" ; var' ; l=val ; eval $v='$l'`  - would echo "OHNO! before assigning var. You could "${v##*[;"$IFS"]}='$l'" to ensure that the string can't expand to anything that won't be evaluated with the =.

Comment: @mikeserv thank you for your comment but I think that is not a valid example. The first argument of the assign script should be a variable name or a variable that contains a variable name that is used on the left hand side of the `=` assignement statement. You can argue that my scrip does not check its argument. That is true. I do not even check if there is any argument or if the number of arguments is valid. But this was by intention. The OP can add such  checks if he wants.

Comment: @mikeserv: I think that your proposal to transform the first argument  silently to a valid variable name is not a good idea: 1) some variable is set/overwritten that was not intended by the user. 2) the error is hidden from the user of the function. That is never a good idea. One should simply raise an error if that happens.

Comment: @mikeserv: It is interesting when one wants to use your variable `v` (better its value) as second argument of the assign function. So its value should be on the right hand side of an assignement. It is necessaary to quote the argument of the function `assign`. I added this subtlety to my posting.

Comment: Probably true - and you're not actually using eval in your final example - which is wise - so it doesn't really matter. But what I'm saying is that any code that uses eval and takes user input is inherently risky - and if you did use your example, I could make the function designed to change my path to rm my path with little effort.

Comment: The `eval` example you present can be made to execute arbitrary code. Still.

Comment: @mikeserv: For what value of `V` the function `assign PATH "$V"`  executes some malicious code?

Answer (score 2):

With a few tricks you can actually pass named parameters to functions, along with arrays (tested in bash 3 and 4).

The method I developed allows you to access parameters passed to a function like this:

```
testPassingParams() {

    @var hello
    l=4 @array anArrayWithFourElements
    l=2 @array anotherArrayWithTwo
    @var anotherSingle
    @reference table   # references only work in bash >=4.3
    @params anArrayOfVariedSize

    test "$hello" = "$1" && echo correct
    #
    test "${anArrayWithFourElements[0]}" = "$2" && echo correct
    test "${anArrayWithFourElements[1]}" = "$3" && echo correct
    test "${anArrayWithFourElements[2]}" = "$4" && echo correct
    # etc...
    #
    test "${anotherArrayWithTwo[0]}" = "$6" && echo correct
    test "${anotherArrayWithTwo[1]}" = "$7" && echo correct
    #
    test "$anotherSingle" = "$8" && echo correct
    #
    test "${table[test]}" = "works"
    table[inside]="adding a new value"
    #
    # I'm using * just in this example:
    test "${anArrayOfVariedSize[*]}" = "${*:10}" && echo correct
}

fourElements=( a1 a2 "a3 with spaces" a4 )
twoElements=( b1 b2 )
declare -A assocArray
assocArray[test]="works"

testPassingParams "first" "${fourElements[@]}" "${twoElements[@]}" "single with spaces" assocArray "and more... " "even more..."

test "${assocArray[inside]}" = "adding a new value"
```

In other words, not only you can call your parameters by their names (which makes up for a more readable core), you can actually pass arrays (and references to variables - this feature works only in bash 4.3 though)! Plus, the mapped variables are all in the local scope, just as $1 (and others).

The code that makes this work is pretty light and works both in bash 3 and bash 4 (these are the only versions I've tested it with). If you're interested in more tricks like this that make developing with bash much nicer and easier, you can take a look at my [Bash Infinity Framework](https://github.com/niieani/bash-oo-framework), the code below was developed for that purpose.

```
Function.AssignParamLocally() {
    local commandWithArgs=( $1 )
    local command="${commandWithArgs[0]}"

    shift

    if [[ "$command" == "trap" || "$command" == "l="* || "$command" == "_type="* ]]
    then
        paramNo+=-1
        return 0
    fi

    if [[ "$command" != "local" ]]
    then
        assignNormalCodeStarted=true
    fi

    local varDeclaration="${commandWithArgs[1]}"
    if [[ $varDeclaration == '-n' ]]
    then
        varDeclaration="${commandWithArgs[2]}"
    fi
    local varName="${varDeclaration%%=*}"

    # var value is only important if making an object later on from it
    local varValue="${varDeclaration#*=}"

    if [[ ! -z $assignVarType ]]
    then
        local previousParamNo=$(expr $paramNo - 1)

        if [[ "$assignVarType" == "array" ]]
        then
            # passing array:
            execute="$assignVarName=( \"\${@:$previousParamNo:$assignArrLength}\" )"
            eval "$execute"
            paramNo+=$(expr $assignArrLength - 1)

            unset assignArrLength
        elif [[ "$assignVarType" == "params" ]]
        then
            execute="$assignVarName=( \"\${@:$previousParamNo}\" )"
            eval "$execute"
        elif [[ "$assignVarType" == "reference" ]]
        then
            execute="$assignVarName=\"\$$previousParamNo\""
            eval "$execute"
        elif [[ ! -z "${!previousParamNo}" ]]
        then
            execute="$assignVarName=\"\$$previousParamNo\""
            eval "$execute"
        fi
    fi

    assignVarType="$__capture_type"
    assignVarName="$varName"
    assignArrLength="$__capture_arrLength"
}

Function.CaptureParams() {
    __capture_type="$_type"
    __capture_arrLength="$l"
}

alias @trapAssign='Function.CaptureParams; trap "declare -i \"paramNo+=1\"; Function.AssignParamLocally \"\$BASH_COMMAND\" \"\$@\"; [[ \$assignNormalCodeStarted = true ]] && trap - DEBUG && unset assignVarType && unset assignVarName && unset assignNormalCodeStarted && unset paramNo" DEBUG; '
alias @param='@trapAssign local'
alias @reference='_type=reference @trapAssign local -n'
alias @var='_type=var @param'
alias @params='_type=params @param'
alias @array='_type=array @param'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
assign () 
{ 
    if [ -z ${!1} ]; then
        eval $1=$2
    else
        if [[ ${!1} != *$2* ]]; then
            eval $1=${!1}:$2
        fi
    fi
}

$ echo =$x=
==
$ assign x y
$ echo =$x=
=y=
$ assign x y
$ echo =$x=
=y=
$ assign x z
$ echo =$x=
=y:z=
```

Does this fit?

Comment: hi, I tried to do it like yours, but not working, sorry for being a newbie. Could you please tell me what is wrong with this [script](http://pastebin.com/L8hqaKSQ)?

Comment: Your usage of `eval` is susceptible to arbitrary command execution.

Comment: You have an idea to make zhe `eval` lines safer? Normally, when I think I need eval, I decide not to use *sh and switch to a different language instead. On the other hand, using this in scrips to append entries to some PATH-like variables, it will run with string constants and not user input...

Comment: you can do *`eval`* safely - but it takes a lot of thought. If you're just trying to reference a parameter, you'd wanna do something like this: *`eval "$1=\"\$2\""`* that way on *`eval's`* first pass it only evaluates $1 and on the second it does value="$2". But you need to do something else - this is unnecessary here.

Comment: Actually, my above comment is wrong, too. You've gotta do `"${1##*[;"$IFS"]}=\"\$2\""` - and even that comes with no warranty. Or `eval "$(set -- $1 ; shift $(($#-1)) ; echo $1)=\"\$2\""`. It's not easy.

Answer (score 1):

Named arguments simply aren't how Bash's syntax was designed. Bash was designed to be an iterative improvement upon the Bourne shell. As such it needs to ensure certain things work between the two shells as much as possible. So it isn't *meant* to be easier to script with overall, it's just meant to be better than Bourne while ensuring that if you take a script from a Bourne environment over to `bash` it's as easy as possible. That isn't trivial since a lot of shells still treat Bourne as a de facto standard. Since people write their scripts to be Bourne-compatible (for this portability) the need remains in force and is unlikely to ever change.

You're probably better off looking at a different shell script (like `python` or something) entirely if it's at all feasible. If you're running up against a language's limitations, you need to start using a new language.

Comment: Maybe early in `bash`'s life this was true. But now specific provisions are made. Full reference variables are now available in `bash 4.3` - see [derobert's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122640/48083).

Comment: And if you look here, you'll see you can do this kind of thing really easily even with just POSIX portable code: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120531/52934

Answer (score 1):

With standard `sh` syntax (would work in `bash`, and not only in `bash`), you could do:

```
assign() {
  eval '
    case :${'"$1"'}: in
      (::) '"$1"'=$2;;   # was empty, copy
      (*:"$2":*) ;;      # already there, do nothing
      (*) '"$1"'=$1:$2;; # otherwise, append with a :
    esac'
}
```

Like for solutions using `bash`'s `declare`, it's *safe* as long as `$1` contains a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

#### ON NAMED ARGS:

This is very simply done and *`bash`* is not required at all - this is the basic POSIX specified behavior of assignment via parameter expansion:

```
: ${PATH:=this is only assigned to \$PATH if \$PATH is null or unset}
```

To demo in a similar vein to @Graeme, but in a portable way:

```
_fn() { echo "$1 ${2:-"$1"} $str" ; }

% str= ; _fn "${str:=hello}"
> hello hello hello
```

And there I only do *`str=`* to ensure it has a null value, because parameter expansion has the built-in safeguard against reassigning shell environment inline if it's already set.

#### SOLUTION:

For your specific problem, I don't believe named arguments are necessary, though they're certainly possible. Use ***`$IFS`*** instead:

```
assign() { oFS=$IFS ; IFS=: ; add=$* 
    set -- $PATH ; for p in $add ; do { 
        for d ; do [ -z "${d%"$p"}" ] && break 
        done ; } || set -- $* $p ; done
    PATH= ; echo "${PATH:="$*"}" ; IFS=$oFS
}
```

Here's what I get when I run it:

```
% PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/yes/bin
% assign \
    /usr/bin \
    /usr/yes/bin \
    /usr/nope/bin \
    /usr/bin \
    /nope/usr/bin \
    /usr/nope/bin

> /usr/bin:/usr/yes/bin:/usr/nope/bin:/nope/usr/bin

% echo "$PATH"
> /usr/bin:/usr/yes/bin:/usr/nope/bin:/nope/usr/bin

% dir="/some crazy/dir"
% p=`assign /usr/bin /usr/bin/new "$dir"`
% echo "$p" ; echo "$PATH"
> /usr/bin:/usr/yes/bin:/usr/nope/bin:/nope/usr/bin:/some crazy/dir:/usr/bin/new
> /usr/bin:/usr/yes/bin:/usr/nope/bin:/nope/usr/bin:/some crazy/dir:/usr/bin/new
```

Notice it only added the arguments that weren't already in ***`$PATH`*** or that came before? Or even that it took more than one argument at all? *`$IFS`* is handy.

Comment: hi, I failed to follow, so could you please elaborate it a little bit more? thanks.

Comment: I'm already doing so... Just a few more moments please...

Comment: @ramgorur Any better? Sorry, but real life intruded and it took me a little longer than I expected to finish the write-up.

Comment: same here as well, succumbed to real life. Looks like lots of different approaches to code this thing, let me give me sometime to settle on the best one.

Comment: @ramgorur - of course, just wanted to make sure I didn't leave you hanging. About this - you choose whatever you want, man. I will say none of the other answers I can see offer as concise, portable, or as robust a solution as *`assign`* does here. If you have questions about how it works, I'd be happy to answer. And by the way, if you really want named arguments, you might wanna look at this other answer of mine in which I show how to declare a function named for another function's arguments: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120531/52934

Answer (score -2):

I can't find anything like ruby, python, etc. but this feels closer to me

```bsh
foo() {
  BAR="$1"; BAZ="$2"; QUUX="$3"; CORGE="$4"
  ...
}
```

Readability is better in my opinion, 4 lines is excessive for declaring your parameter names. Looks closer to modern languages as well.

Comment: (1) The question is about shell functions.  Your answer presents a skeleton shell function.  Beyond that, your answer has nothing to do with the question.  (2) You think it *increases* readability to take separate lines and concatenate them into one line, with semicolons as separators?  I believe that you’ve got it backwards; that your one-line style is ***less*** readable than the multi-line style.

Comment: If reducing unnecessary parts is the point, then why the quotes and semicolons? `a=$1 b=$2 ...` works just as well.