# Named bash function parameters

Tags: bash, shell-script

Always wondered this, but never fully investigated - is there any way to get named parameters in bash?

For example, I have this:

```
function ql_maybe_fail {
  if [[ "$1" == "true" ]]; then
      echo "quicklock: exiting with 1 since fail flag was set for your 'ql_release_lock' command. "
      exit 1;
  fi
}
```

is it somehow possible to convert it to something like this:

```
function ql_maybe_fail (isFail) {
  if [[ "$isFail" == "true" ]]; then
      echo "quicklock: exiting with 1 since fail flag was set for your 'ql_release_lock' command. "
      exit 1;
  fi
}
```

Comment: Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122632/a-bash-function-that-takes-argument-like-other-languages

Comment: damn those answers are all so unclear...after reading, I guess the answer is a big fat no, lol

Comment: The best I've found is this answer over on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948533

Comment: What's the problem that you are trying to solve that requires this to work?

Comment: it's just for convenience - most programming languages have named arguments, etc, for a reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions in Bash currently do not support user-named arguments.

Answer (score 4):

This workaround might help, but it is not well testet:

```
fun () {
    v1=$1
    v2=$2
    for v in "$v1" "$v2"
    do
       case "$v" in
           name=*) name=${v/*=/};;
           age=*)  age=${v/*=/};;
           *)    echo "unexpected $v, please use name and age" ;;
       esac
    done

    echo "name=$name age=$age"
}
```

output:

```
fun "name=John" "age=22"
name=John age=22
fun "age=22" "name=John"
name=John age=22
```

Comment: yeah, it's just not the same lol

Comment: Well, for your sample (`function ql_maybe_fail (isFail) {`) just write `function ql_maybe_fail () { isFail=$1` - where is the problem?

Comment: no problem just an extra line of code I guess