# Passing arguments to su-provided shell

Tags: bash, shell, su, options

`man su` says:

```
You can use the -- argument to separate su options from the arguments
supplied to the shell.
```

`man bash` says:

```
--        A  --  signals  the  end of options and disables further option
          processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames
          and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.
```

Well then, let's see:

```
[root ~] su - yuri -c 'echo "$*"' -- 1 2 3
2 3
[root ~] su - yuri -c 'echo "$*"' -- -- 1 2 3                                                       
2 3
[root ~] su - yuri -c 'echo "$*"' -- - 1 2 3                                                        
1 2 3
[root ~] su - yuri -c 'echo "$*"' - 1 2 3                                                           
1 2 3
```

What I expected (output of the second command differs):

```
[root ~] su - yuri -c 'echo "$*"' -- 1 2 3
2 3
[root ~] su - yuri -c 'echo "$*"' -- -- 1 2 3                                                       
1 2 3
[root ~] su - yuri -c 'echo "$*"' -- - 1 2 3                                                        
1 2 3
[root ~] su - yuri -c 'echo "$*"' - 1 2 3                                                           
1 2 3
```

Probably not much of an issue. But what's happening there? The second and the third variants seem like the way to go, but one of them doesn't work. The fourth one seems unreliable, `-` can be treated as `su`'s option.

Comment: That's strange. I get exactly the results you expect (and I also agree with those expectations). I mean, in case of a second invocation, I do get "1 2 3" as an output. I'm using `bash 4.2.45` on both source and destination accounts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is happening is that the first argument you supply to the shell is the `$0` parameter, (usually this would be the name of the shell). It is not included when you do `echo $*` since `$*` is every argument apart from `$0`.

Example:

```
# su - graeme -c 'echo "\$0 - $0"; echo "\$* - $*"' -- sh 1 2 3
$0 - sh
$* - 1 2 3
```

#### Update

Doing the following command:

```
strace -f su graeme -c 'echo $0; echo "$*"' -- -- 1 2 3
```

yields the strace line:

```
[pid  9609] execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "echo $0; echo \"$*\"", "1", "2", "3"], [/* 27 vars */] <unfinished ...>
```

So somehow it seems that in this case `su` is gobbling up the extra `--` without passing it to bash, possibly due to a bug (or at least undocumented behaviour). It won't however eat up any more than two of the `--` arguments:

```
# su graeme -c 'echo $0; echo "$*"' -- -- -- 1 2 3
--
1 2 3
```

Comment: That I understand. I do: `su - yuri -c 'echo "$*"' -- -- 1 2 3`, the shell supposedly gets `-- 1 2 3`, but outputs only `2 3`. Does it even make any sense?

Comment: And when I do `bash -c 'echo $*' -- 1 2 3`, it outputs `1 2 3` as expected.

Comment: @x-yuri, updated. This seems to be an `su` bug.

Answer (score 6):

Actually @Graeme's answer - and your question - are just referencing side-effects of how the shell handles `"$@positional $*parameters".` These are assigned by the shell to its arguments upon invocation and at any time later with the built-in `set` utility. They can be called upon at any time with either `"$*"` which splits each positional with the first character in `"$IFS"` or `"$@"` which quotes each positional and splits them with all of `"$IFS."`

```
man set

    NAME
       set — set or unset options and positional parameters

SYNOPSIS
       set [−abCefhmnuvx] [−o option] [argument...]

       set [+abCefhmnuvx] [+o option] [argument...]

       set −− [argument...]

       set −o

       set +o
```

If you already have the values that you're feeding the shell, you don't need to `--` three times. Shell parameters are `set`able - always, at any time, not just at invocation *(excepting $0 and -i):*

```
su - mikeserv -c 'set -- "$*" ; echo "$*" ; 
    set -- 4 5 6 ; echo "$*"' -- -- 7 8 9

7 8 9
4 5 6
```

And all of that shell quoting can be confusing. This simplifies things a little:

```
( set -- 4 5 6
    su - mikeserv 4<<-\CMD /dev/fd/4 "$@"
    echo $0 "$*"
    set -- "$*"
    echo "$*"
    set -- 7 8 9
    echo "$*"
CMD
)

/dev/fd/4 4 5 6
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

The parent shell's arguments are `set` to 4, 5, and 6 and are then passed to the subshell invoked by `su` via the positional `parameter "$@array".`

Note how I `( subshell )` the above command - I do that because I don't want to mess around with my current shell environment - because I can inadvertently change something I'd rather not if I did with `set.`

#### ABOUT REDIRECTION:

First of all, your Unix system works with files - file permissions, file contents, file attributes. In one way or another, every data object you use can *(and, at least in my opinion, should)* be addressed as a file. Redirection points to a file - that's all. A `<<HERE-DOCUMENT` will describe a file in-line then redirect it. Either shell expansions are interpreted or they are not.

The asker notes in the comments below that when he attempts to use this method as the `root` user he is delivered a permissions error. When I responded I suggested he `chown` or `chgrp` the `/dev/fd/${num}` special file, but this is probably not the best method. The reason he encounters this issue is `root` is granted `read` permissions but ***not*** `execute` permissions. You can easily handle this by just avoiding an `exec` call. Instead of invoking the `/dev/fd/${num}` file directly on the command line do:

```
su -c '. /dev/fd/'${num} ${num}<<SCRIPT
```

Using two heredocs can help with escaping. Here is what happens in every case:

#### NO SET IN `<<HEREDOC`

```
sh 3<<\CMD /dev/fd/3
    ( echo 'without set "$@" or \$@ in here-doc' ; echo
    set -- '1 "2" 3' 4 "5 6"
    su - mikeserv 4<<-UNQUOTED 5<<-\PREQUOTED /dev/fd/4
        echo UNQUOTED; echo $0 "$*"
        printf "%s\\t\\t%s\\t\\t%s\\t\\t%s\\n" $(printf "'%s' " "$@") \\
                $@ '$@' "$@" '"$@"' "'$@'" \$@ '\$@' "\$@" '"\$@"'
    . /dev/fd/5
    UNQUOTED
        echo PREQUOTED ; echo $0 "$*"
        printf "%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n" $(printf "'%s' " "$@") \
                $@ '$@' "$@" '"$@"' \$@ '\$@' "\$@" '"\$@"'
    PREQUOTED
    )
CMD
```

#### OUTPUT

```
without set "$@" or \$@ in here-doc

UNQUOTED
/dev/fd/3 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 "2" 3         4               5 6             1
2               3               4               5
6               1 "2" 3 4 5 6           1 2 3 4 5 6             "1 "2" 3 4 5 6"
'1 2 3 4 5 6'           $@              "$@"
PREQUOTED
/dev/fd/5
''              $@              "$@"            $@
\$@             $@              "\$@"
```

#### SET `"$@"`IN `<<HEREDOC`

```
sh 3<<\CMD /dev/fd/3
    ( echo 'set "$@" and \$@ in here-doc' ; echo
    set -- '1 "2" 3' 4 "5 6"
    su - mikeserv 4<<-UNQUOTED 5<<-\PREQUOTED /dev/fd/4
        set -- "$@" "\$@"
        echo UNQUOTED; echo $0 "$*"
        printf "%s\\t\\t%s\\t\\t%s\\t\\t%s\\n" $(printf "'%s' " "$@") \\
                $@ '$@' "$@" '"$@"' "'$@'" \$@ '\$@' "\$@" '"\$@"'
        . /dev/fd/5
    UNQUOTED
        set -- "$@" "\$@"
        echo PREQUOTED ; echo $0 "$*"
        printf "%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n" $(printf "'%s' " "$@") \
                $@ '$@' "$@" '"$@"' \$@ '\$@' "\$@" '"\$@"'
    PREQUOTED
)
CMD
```

#### OUTPUT

```
set "$@" and \$@ in here-doc

UNQUOTED
/dev/fd/3 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 "2" 3         4               5 6             1
2               3               4               5
6               1 "2" 3 4 5 6           1 2 3 4 5 6             "1 "2" 3 4 5 6"
'1 2 3 4 5 6'           1 2 3 4 5 6             $@              1 2 3 4 5 6
"$@"
PREQUOTED
/dev/fd/5 1 2 3 4 5 6 $@
'1              2               3               4
5               6'              '$@'            1 2 3 4 5 6
$@              $@              1 2 3 4 5 6             $@
"$@"            $@              \$@             $@
"\$@"
```

#### SET `"$@"`AND MORE IN `<<HEREDOC`

```
sh 3<<\CMD /dev/fd/3
    ( echo 'set "$@" and \$@ AND additional parameters in here-doc' ; echo
    set -- '1 "2" 3' 4 "5 6"
    su - mikeserv 4<<-UNQUOTED 5<<-\PREQUOTED /dev/fd/4
        set -- "$@" "\$@" '7 "8" 9' 10 "11 12"
        echo UNQUOTED; echo $0 "$*"
        printf "%s\\t\\t%s\\t\\t%s\\t\\t%s\\n" $(printf "'%s' " "$@") \\
                $@ '$@' "$@" '"$@"' "'$@'" \$@ '\$@' "\$@" '"\$@"'
        . /dev/fd/5
    UNQUOTED
        set -- "$@" "\$@" '13 "14" 15' 16 "17 18"
        echo PREQUOTED ; echo $0 "$*"
        printf "%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n" $(printf "'%s' " "$@") \
                $@ '$@' "$@" '"$@"' \$@ '\$@' "\$@" '"\$@"'
    PREQUOTED
    )
CMD
```

#### OUTPUT

```
set "$@" and \$@ AND additional parameters in here-doc

UNQUOTED
/dev/fd/3 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 "2" 3         4               5 6             1
2               3               4               5
6               1 "2" 3 4 5 6           1 2 3 4 5 6             "1 "2" 3 4 5 6"
'1 2 3 4 5 6'           1 2 3 4 5 6             7 "8" 9         10
11 12           $@              1 2 3 4 5 6             7 "8" 9
10              11 12           "$@"
PREQUOTED
/dev/fd/5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 "8" 9 10 11 12 $@ 13 "14" 15 16 17 18
'1              2               3               4
5               6'              '7              "8"
9'              '10'            '11             12'
'$@'            '13             "14"            15'
'16'            '17             18'             1 2 3 4 5 6
7 "8" 9         10              11 12           $@
13 "14" 15              16              17 18           $@
1 2 3 4 5 6             7 "8" 9         10              11 12
$@              13 "14" 15              16              17 18
"$@"            $@              \$@             $@
"\$@"
```

Comment: The problem is your first script gives me `"8 9\n4 5 6\n"`. I'm running `debian 6`, `bash-4.1.5` and [`su`](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/login).

Comment: @x-yuri - and the second, which avoids all of the quoting mess?

Comment: If run from `root` it says: `-su: /dev/fd/4: Permission denied`. Do you know what that means, by the way? Otherwise it outputs as you say, but it doesn't address the question. Question is about using `--` and `-`.

Comment: @x-yuri I think that means you should `chown /dev/fd/4` for the duration you'll need it, or just `chgrp`. I haven't got much time to test right now. But that is a little beside the point, as was the other you don't need to pass arguments on the tail end at all - just work your quoting. See it now?

Comment: If we omit the issue with `su` being unable to work with redirected `stdin`, passing arguments is still better then injecting them into the command. Because in the latter case you need to escape them.

Comment: @x-yuri Remove the escape from the here-doc. I \CMD so that it wasn't preinterpreted.

Comment: You still need to escape parameters, that `4 5 6` thing in real life may contain double quote, for instance.

Comment: @x-yuri No, you don't. Look above now. If it contains double-quotes you use "$@" - that's what it's for. In a pre-interpreted here-doc use '$@'for all args as $1 or $@ for passing identically. See here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120528/how-to-define-similar-bash-function-at-once/120531#120531

Comment: @x-yuri - I updated it again to demo exactly what happens for every type of quoting in a here-doc.

Comment: @x-yuri - I think I realize what your problem was permissions problem was and how to fix it without `chown` it. You would do `. /dev/fd/${num}` - I'm about to add this to the answer.

Comment: Let me put it the other way. Let's switch to `bash` instead of `su` here for simplicity. [This](http://sprunge.us/LPTO) works, and [this](http://sprunge.us/FOiJ) doesn't. Can you make the second script work without passing arguments to `bash`? On a side note, are `/dev/fd/N` descriptors global, or every process have different files there?

Comment: I see `/dev/fd/N` is a symbolic link to `/proc/self/fd`. So, if we're changing user, we get: `-su: /dev/fd/4: Permission denied`. If we're trying to execute the script under another user, that is.

Comment: @x-yuri that's why I recommended you don't execute it but you `.dot` source it. See how its done above? And yes, `/dev/fd/${num}` is global. `/dev/fd/N` is not symbolic link to `/proc` - its a symbolic link to whatever your file descriptor is. See here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123492/can-a-running-script-identify-the-logging-context/123501#123501