# Can a running script identify the logging context?

Tags: shell, files, stdout, file-descriptors, stderr

Let us say I redirect the `STDOUT`, `STDERR` of a program to files.

```
./script.sh 1> output.log 2> error.log
```

Can the running program find this out i.e. know the paths to these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`lsof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) to list the open files of the shell process. Use `-a -p $$` to limit the output to the shell process (`$$`), `-d 1` to limit the output to file descriptor 1 (for instance), and `-F n` to print the output in parseable form. Here's a shell snippet that copes with arbitrary characters in file names:

```
output_file=$(lsof -a -p $$ -d 1 -F pn; echo .)
output_file=${output_file%.}
output_file=${output_file#n}
```

If the file name doesn't contain a newline, you'll be able to get away with `output_file=$(lsof -a -p $$ -d 1 -F pn | sed -n '2s/.//p')`.

Note that the file name may not always exist, in particular if the file has been deleted.

Under Linux, another way to access the file names is through `/proc/$$/fd`: `/proc/$$/fd/1` is a slightly magic symbolic link to the file opened by the shell on file descriptor 1 (the link works even if the file name returned by `readlink` doesn't exist, for example in the case of a deleted file).

It is usually a very bad idea to make any use of the information obtained this way. If someone calls your script with the output redirected to a file, they won't like it if you behave differently because of the location of the file, or affect the file in ways other than appending to it. There is one exception: you may want to react differently depending on whether you're writing to a terminal or to something else (pipe, socket, file), for example to display colors or progress indicators on a terminal. There is a specific test to determine whether a file descriptor is connected to a terminal:

```
if [ -t 2 ]; then
  # stderr is a terminal
  printf 1>&2 '\e[31mError: widget not found\e[0m'
else
  # stderr is not a terminal
  echo 1>&2 'Error: widget not found'
fi
```

Comment: This is good - but it depends on `lsof,` of course. Though not the last bit, obviously.

Comment: @mikeserv That's the portable way to do it. I do also mention the Linux way.

Comment: I should clarify - `lsof` is awesome - its just not always there. Neither is `readlink` for that matter - though I think the chances are a little better. - I agree. I was writing that addendum before even I knew you had replied. Speaking of readlink - my preference is for `realpath,` actually.

Comment: In any case, it would be hard to argue you did a worse job of explaining it than anyone else did here - especially me. You've already got my vote.

Comment: @mikeserv If `/proc/<pid>/fd` is there, then there's a very good chance that you're running Linux (but it could also be Solaris or some other SysV unices) and therefore `readlink` is available (it's in GNU coreutils and BusyBox). `realpath` is less common: under Linux, it's a deprecated program from the time before `readlink`, which may still be installed if some legacy application depends on it.

Comment: Really? `realpath` is deprecated? I thought i remembered reading it it was just added to GNU in 2012. Maybe I've got it backwards.

Comment: Looks like we were both right. New tool, same old name. Though i guess just as GNU brings it in, the BSDs let it go... http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=77ea441f79aa115f79b47d9c1fc9c0004c5c7111

Answer (score 5):

```
{ readlink /dev/fd/[1,2] ; echo "out" ; } >./file 2>./error    
{ readlink /dev/fd/0 ; cat ; } <./file
```

OUTPUT:

```
/home/mikeserv/file
/home/mikeserv/file
/home/mikeserv/error
out

{ readlink /proc/$$/fd/[1,2] ; echo out ; } >./file 2>./error
{ readlink /proc/$$/fd/0 ; cat ; } <./file
```

OUTPUT:

```
/home/mikeserv/file
/home/mikeserv/file
/home/mikeserv/error    
out
```

Comment: This is useful, but it should be noted that not all unixes implement the proc file systems.

Comment: A very useful note indeed.

Comment: Although, to be fair, the unixes 99 % of the people posting here use do... :-)

Comment: @JennyD - when I hover my mouse cursor over the ^ arrow next to an answer it says - "This answer is useful..."

Comment: @JennyD I think we have more than 1% of *BSD users (including OSX).

Comment: @Gilles - is it just that `/proc` is missing for BSDs or are the `/dev/fd/N` links also unavailable?

Comment: @mikeserv I think `/dev/fd/N` exist, but don't provide any information as to what's behind the file (they aren't symlinks).

Comment: @Gilles - that's valuable information - thanks very much. Maybe I'll make that a question and we'll both find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `STDOUT` will be saved to file `output.log` and `STDERR` will be saved to file `error.log`. Both files are saved in the same directory with `script.sh`.

If you want your program "know the path to these files", you must use absolute path:

```
./script.sh > /path/to/output.log 2> /path/to/error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The `output.log` and `error.log` files are created in the current directory i.e. the `$PWD` variable value.
If you want your program to use these files later, just save their directory in a variable before running your script. Here is an example :

```
OUTDIR=$PWD
./script.sh 1> output.log 2> error.log
# Whatever you want to do else ...
echo The output file : =======
cat $OUTDIR/output.log
echo =========================
echo 
echo The errors file : =======
cat $OUTDIR/error.log
echo =========================
```